Disambiguating the [dbconnection] tag
As part of the connect burnination, I came across dbconnection, which looks like it could use a disambiguation followed by merge/removal:

No tag wiki guidance

Currently 235 questions

Has 46 questions also tagged c#, 13 tagged .net, 8 with ado.net, and 7 with asp.net (less than 74 .NET total, since some share those tags) - A good portion of those are referring to the .NET DbConnection class and could be retagged with a better tag (propose: .net-dbconnection or other suggestion).

Also has 11 r questions that appear to be about R dbconnect and should be retagged as r-dbconnect instead. - Thanks @ErikA for retagging these asr-dbi.

Most of the remainder appear to be mergeable into database-connection


Looking for help from any .NET SMEs to confirm my suspicions on the DbConnection topic.  Likewise, the few r ones could use an R SME, of course.
Other shared tags

I've retagged the R questions as appropriately (mostly with r-dbi and other more useful tags). The DBI mess is perhaps a problem for another day
